# Cross Platform database encryption in Shared Project Xamarin

Tags: encryption, xamarin, sqlite.net

I am using Xamarin to develop iOS and Android application. I have created one shared project which is common for both platforms.
As I am using database its common and put in shared project. I need to encrypt database file.

Project structure is like [Tasky](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/Tasky/Shared).

I have replaced SQLite.cs file from this GitHub [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/) as suggested by Xamarin.

No SQL- cipher component I can use as its paid one.

Note: Other way round instead is encrypting DB file by AES of C#.

But, I need a good approach.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

SQLCipher is also available as free community edition. A little more work to compile the C code yourself but nothing too bad. I had to do it for one of my earlier projects even though I had the commercial license as some of the features (data types) were missing.

For example here, you could get the SQLCipher native library:
https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher

SQLite source code (includes XCode project as well): https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher

Comment: But, conversion of c source itself be another long life project.

Comment: Conversion? No, just compile it for Android and iOS. Of course if one doesn't have much C experience compiling can be a taunting task by itself. See my update for a link to a GitHub project for Android. It should give you the native C libraries. There is also an iOS version if you search for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the xamarin android binding project by importing sqlcipher aar file and resulting DLL can be used for the db encryption.
Checkout the complete example code [here](http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2017/09/encrypt-android-sqlite-database-using.html) implemented using open-source sqlcipher community edition.